# Clean Prototype fork (good idea?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, js.class

Is there a [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) fork that doesn't come with any DOM/ajax parts? I really prefer jQuery for these, and would rather not carry the extra baggage. So far I've been using the excellent [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/classes.html) library, which doesn't even touch built-in classes prototypes. However, I've been outgrowing its capabilities, and prototype would fill its holes.

The biggest issue is: how bad is for a library to require prototype? Even such clean one (without the dom helpers, such as $ and $$).

Comment: Why do you need Prototype if you already have jQuery?  It's not clear from your question what your goal is.

Comment: The other parts of prototype? But urls are woth more than words: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/string/, http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class/, http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/, http://api.prototypejs.org/language/object/. JS.Class has almost all: http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/classes.html. Among its pitfalls: enumerables on JS.Class are not composable. They are on prototype.

Comment: And by composable, I mean chainable: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CollectionClosureMethod.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype 2.0.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/prototype-2-0-will-not-extend-the-dom

It's not out yet, though.

Comment: Well, maybe I can get by with JS.Class for a while more.